# Zend Form : pass var from controller to form

Tags: forms, zend-framework, zend-form, parameter-passing

i have this problem : i want to pass to my form a param because i need it to complete a select.

Here's my code

Controller :

```
    $p1 = $this->getRequest()->getParam ( '1' );
    $p2 = $this->getRequest()->getParam ( '2' );
    $utentepost = new Application_Model_myMapper();
    $data = $utentepost->populateFormInsert($p1, $p2);
    $form = new Application_Form_myForm();
    $form->populate($data);
     ...
```

Form

public function init()
    {

```
    $this->setMethod('post');

    $this->addElement('text', 'p1', array());
    $this->addElement('text', 'p2', array());

    $this->addElement('select', 'sede_id', array(
            'label'         => 'Sede',
            'required'      => true,
            'multiOptions'  => $this->_setSelect($p1),  
        ));
        .... ....
     protected function _setSelect($p1) {
       ... call model/mapper to execute sql query
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: I answered a similar question here about passing variables to a form: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607915/zend-form-element-different-render-on-different-action/6609081#6609081

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

if you have an Constructor defined in your form add "parent::..":

```
public function __construct($options = null)
{
    parent::__construct($options);
}
```

now pass the attribs as array to your form:

```
$form = new Application_Form_myForm(array('p1' => $p1, 'p2' => $p2));
```

inside your form:

```
 protected function _setSelect() {
   $p1 = $this->getAttrib('p1');
   ... call model/mapper to execute sql query
 }
```